# Append text to file names which do not contain a dot

Tags: command-line, rename, batch-rename

Given the following files:

```
english_api
english_overview
style.css
```

I want to get:

```
english_api.html
english_overview.html
style.css
```

In other words how to append a text to all files that do Not Contain a dot (`.`) within a directory using terminal.

Obviously there is a lot of files in that folder; I just  wrote 3 as an example.

If I were to, lets say, replace `.css` with `.html` in that folder, I would use:

```
rename .css .html *.css
```

But I cannot really think of a way to match files that do not contain something. Also how to append (vs replace) using `rename` command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this `find` command,

```
find . -type f ! -name "*.*" -exec mv {} {}.html \;
```

It renames the files which doesn't contain dots in their filenames present in the current directory to this `filename.html`format(*added `.html` at the last*).

`.`              --> Represents current directory

`-type f`        --> To do this operation only on files.

`! -name "*.*"` --> print the name of the files which doesn't have dots in their name.

`-exec mv {} {}.html`  --> `find` command perform this move(or)rename operation on the extracted filenames.

`\;`   -->  Represents the end of `find` command.

Answer (score 6):

In bash, you could use [extended shell globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) e.g.

```
for file in path/to/files/!(*.*); do echo mv "$file" "$file.html"; done
```

(remove the `echo` once you've confirmed it is matching the correct pattern). If extended globbing is not already enabled, you can enable it with `shopt -s extglob`.

Another option is using the perl-based `rename` function with a regex that excludes literal `.`

```
rename -nv 's/^[^.]+$/$&.html/' path/to/files/*
```

(remove the `n` option once you have confirmed it is matching the correct pattern).

Comment: `for file in path/to/files/!(*.*); do echo mv "$file" "$file.html"; done` command renames the directories also.

Answer (score 2):

My prefered in cases like this is `mmv`. It is not installed by default in Ubuntu, but you can install using `sudo apt-get install mmv` command.

In your case you need to use it two times:

1. Rename all files from current directory by adding `.html` at the end of each file name:

   ```
   mmv -v '*' '#1.html'
   ```
2. Rename again (back) all files which had previously in their names one or more `.` (dots):

   ```
   mmv -v '*.*.html' '#1.#2'
   ```

Or, in one line:

```
mmv -v '*' '#1.html' && mmv -v '*.*.html' '#1.#2'
```

`-v` option is not mandatory. I use it only for a verbose output because without it `mmv` performs actions silently.

See [`man mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mmv.1.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

With the Perl rename command ([`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html)), you can add a condition that the file name must contain a dot. If the Perl snippet doesn't change the name of a file, that file is left untouched. Here are a few ways to write this:

```
prename '/\./ or s/$/.html/' *
prename 's/$/.html/ unless /\./' *
prename '$_ .= ".html" unless /\./' *
prename '$_ = "$_.html" unless /\./' *
prename 'if (!/\./) {$_ = "$_.html"}' *
```

Answer (score -2):

The answers are perfect , i also give you another command that do this job :

```
ls -1 | grep -v "\." | awk '{print "mv "$0" "$0".html"}' | sh
```

Some explanation :

```
ls - list directory contents

 -1     list one file per line

grep prints the matching lines.

-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
              is specified by POSIX.)

Awk is mostly used for pattern scanning and processing. It searches one or more files to see if they contain lines that matches with the specified patterns and then perform associated actions.
```

NOTE :

I try your scenario and the command make the job .

Comment: This fails on file names that contain any type of whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.). As a general rule, [you should never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Thats right terdon thank for your comment , but how can i solve this in the same command

Comment: You can't really. There is [almost no safe way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/22222) to parse ls. If you really want to do it using `awk` and `sh`, try something like `printf "'%s'\n" -- !(*.*) | awk '{print "mv -- "$0" "$0".html"}'  | sh`. That will still break on file names with newlines but at least it can deal with spaces. The `--` is needed for cases where you have file names beginning with `-`.